# What should json_decode("true") return?

Tags: php, json

when I try the following in PHP:

```
var_dump(json_decode("123"));

var_dump(json_decode("true"));
```

what I expect is:

```
NULL

NULL
```

but what I actually get is:

```
int(123)

bool(true)
```

Should "123" and "true" be considered valid JSON strings? Or is it a bug in the implementation of json_decode()?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would `json_encode/json_decode` fail on a non-array value?

Comment: according to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit. I think '123' is not valid JSON format, so it should fail. Are my understandings correct?

Comment: @DiMono — *A JSON text is a serialized object or array.* — [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't valid JSON texts, but the `json_decode` function is documented as being able to handle fragments of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that JSON is basically just javascript, and is literally just a plain-text string. Both PHP and Javascript have `true` and `false` constants:

```
php > var_dump(json_decode(true)); // php constant "true", maps to int 1
int(1)
php > var_dump(json_decode('true')); // php string / javascript constant true
bool(true)
php > var_dump(json_decode('"true"')); // json-encoded string "true"
string(4) "true"
```

Your `"123"` may be a PHP string, which leads to some oddities:

```
php > var_dump(json_encode(123));
string(3) "123"
php > var_dump(json_encode("123"));
string(5) ""123""   // not quite what you'd expect.
php > var_dump(json_encode('123'));
string(5) ""123""   // also somewhat unexpected


php > var_dump(json_decode(123));
int(123)
php > var_dump(json_decode('123'));
int(123)
php > var_dump(json_decode('"123"'));
string(3) "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Both results are right.

```
string(4) "true"
```

as a JavaScript string should be converted back to bool(true). Same goes for string(3) "123".